# Tiling Text Over Image at an Angle

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

I use the following code to draw text at the centre of an Image an Angle

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
  g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);
  g.RotateTransform(30);
  SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString("hi", font);
  g.DrawString("hi", font, Brushes.Red, -(textSize.Width / 2), -(textSize.Height / 2));
}
```

I need to Tile the text all over the image like this

[image]

I know that i can increment the coordinates and use a Loop.I have

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i += 20)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y += 20)
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                    {
                        g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);                      
                        g.RotateTransform(30);
                        SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString("my test image", DefaultFont);
                        g.DrawString("my test image", DefaultFont, Brushes.Yellow, i, y);
                       
                    }
                }
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

This produces the following result

[image]

How can i place the text properly by measuring the drawn area properly.May be at a better and faster approach.

Comment: are you adding the same text each time or is it at all dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call an additional `TranslateTransform` to move the text to where you want it at, then draw text with `DrawString` at (0, 0) coordinates. This will rotate each text around its own center, instead of rotating text around the center of the paragraph.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
String text = "TextTile";

Font font = new Font(DefaultFont.Name, 20);
SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
int textwidth = size.ToSize().Width;
int textheight = size.ToSize().Height;

int y_offset = (int)(textwidth * Math.Sin(45 * Math.PI / 180.0));

//the sin of the angle may return zero or negative value, 
//it won't work with this formula
if (y_offset >= 0)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x += textwidth)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y += y_offset)
        {
            //move to this position
            g.TranslateTransform(x, y);

            //draw text rotated around its center
            g.TranslateTransform(textwidth, textheight);
            g.RotateTransform(-45);
            g.TranslateTransform(-textwidth, -textheight);
            g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0);

            //reset
            g.ResetTransform();
        }
    }
}

pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

The above example uses a larger font with size 20. You can set it back to use `DefaultFont.size`. It uses 45 degree angle.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works fine.I was wondering about the performance of this approach if the image is of large size.Is drawing the Text over a Bitmap and drawing that bitmap all over the image a better approach?

Comment: You should automatically have double-buffering. Above code should prepare the image in memory and draw it on the screen only once. The main bottleneck is when the image is drawn on the screen, or when pixels are changed on the screen. By the way, the last line is not necessary: `pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` Alternatively, you can leave the picturebox image to none, then load the image at run time and draw on it, and finally set `pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting the text at the center of the page.
this means your image 0,0 coordinates are at 50%,50% of the other image

if you want to get the result you desired i would suggest you devide the image width in blocks of 25% to get the 16 blocks suggested. then adding one of those text images on the center of each of those blocks.

remember when you adding an image and you want the image to rotate from point not from point 0,0(this is what was happening in your case) of origin you need to state it explicitly, think the command is `rotateorigan` or something in that line,

Comment: Could you post the implementation ?